# A question on reciprocal space for effective mass relation

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

The effective mass is defined as
$$
\frac{1}{m_{ij}^*} = \frac{1}{\hbar^2} \frac{\partial^2\epsilon}{\partial k_i \partial k_j}
$$

where, $m_{ij}^*$ is the effective mass, $\hbar$ is the Planck's constant, $\epsilon$ is the energy and $k_i,\ k_j$ are reciprocal latttice vectors.

I want to find distance between two points in the reciprocal space say the $\Gamma$(0,0,0) point and another arbitrary point $X$(0,0,0.5). The path that I took to do this is:

1. The reciprocal axes vectors are in terms of Cartesian coordinates in units of 2$\pi$/a where a is the lattice constant:

   ```
      b1 = ( -1.000000 -1.000000  1.000000 )
      b2 = (  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 )
      b3 = ( -1.000000  1.000000 -1.000000 )
   ```
2. I have the coordinates of points $\Gamma$ and $X$ in terms of $b1$, $b2$ and $b3$ viz. (0,0,0) and (0,0,0.5)
3. Then I calculated the coordinates of these points in terms of Cartesian coordinates.
4. Then I calculated the distance.

Is this the correct approach?

My question is does $k_x$, $k_y$, and $k_z$ axes used in the relation for effective mass are mutually orthogonal to each other just like the x, y, z axes in Cartesian coordinates?

Or are they related to the reciprocal axes?